# How to reconcile Firebase Auth token refreshing with Server-Side Rendering

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, server-side-rendering

We're using Firebase in a Next.js app at work. I'm new to both, but did my best to read up on both. My problem is more with Firebase, not so much with Next.js. Here's the context:

- In the client app, I make some calls to our API, passing a JWT (the ID token) in an `Authorization` header. The API calls `admin.auth().verifyIdToken` to check that the ID token is fresh enough. This works fine, since I am more or less guaranteed that the ID token gets refreshed regularly (through the use of `onIDTokenChanged` ([doc link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged))
- Now I want to be able to Server-Side Render my app pages. In order to do that, I store the ID token in a cookie readable by the server. But from here on, I have no guarantee that the ID token will be fresh enough next time the user loads the app through a full page load.

I cannot find a server-side equivalent of `onIDTokenChanged`.

This [blog post](https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c) mentions a [google API endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token) to refresh a token. I could hit it from the server and give it a refresh token, but it feels like I'm stepping out of the Firebase realm completely and I'm worried maintaining an ad-hoc system will be a burden.

So my question is, how do people usually reconcile Firebase auth with SSR? Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: The server should not be trying to refresh the ID token for a user. That is an operation that the client should take, and then pass the updated ID token to the server. Instead the server should simply verify the ID token that it gets from the client (typically passed in the `Authorization` header, but in a cookie can also work). Why do you find yourself wanting to refresh the ID token in the server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The reason I find myself wanting to refresh on the server, is that without that potential step, I cannot render user-specific content on the server, which is kind of a bummer to me.

Comment: I get that you need to *have* the ID token on the server to securely find content for that user, but I still don't understand why you have to **refresh** it. While you're processing a single request for that user, it is extremely unlikely that the token expires. And when you get another request from the same user, that request should once again include their ID token. That's quite literally how Firebase's own services deal with this scenario.

Comment: Let's see if I can explain better:
- user logs into FB. My client-side app receives an ID token and a refresh token. I store the ID token into a cookie

- user reloads the page, server gets the cookie which still has about an hour of lifetime remaining.

- user closes browser and goes away

- 3 days later, user returns and loads the site. If the server still has a cookie, the token is expired and there's my problem.

I could give the cookie a lifetime of an hour, but next time the user returns, they'll be logged-out.

Is there no way to guarantee logged-in SSR works in the long run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had that same problem recently, and I solved by handling it myself. I created a very simple page responsible for forcing firebase token refresh, and redirecting user back to the requested page. It's something like this:

- On the server-side, check for token `exp` value after extracting it from cookies (If you're using firebase-admin on that server, it will probably tell you as an error after verifying it)

```js
// Could be a handler like this
const handleTokenCookie = (context) => {
  try {
    const token = parseTokenFromCookie(context.req.headers.cookie)
    await verifyToken(token)
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'TokenExpired') {
      // If expired, user will be redirected to /refresh page, which will force a client-side
      // token refresh, and then redirect user back to the desired page
      const encodedPath = encodeURIComponent(context.req.url)
      context.res.writeHead(302, {
        // Note that encoding avoids URI problems, and `req.url` will also
        // keep any query params intact
        Location: `/refresh?redirect=${encodedPath}`
      })
      context.res.end()
    } else {
      // Other authorization errors...
    }
  }
}
```

This handler can be used on the /pages, like this

```js
// /pages/any-page.js
export async function getServerSideProps (context) {
  const token = await handleTokenCookie(context)
  if (!token) {
    // Token is invalid! User is being redirected to /refresh page
    return {}
  }

  // Your code...
}
```

- Now you need to create a simple `/refresh` page, responsible for forcing firebase token refresh on client-side, and after both token and cookie are updated, it should redirect user back to the desired page.

```js
// /pages/refresh.js

const Refresh = () => {
  // This hook is something like https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication/utils/auth/useUser.js
  const { user } = useUser()
  React.useEffect(function forceTokenRefresh () {
    // You should also handle the case where currentUser is still being loaded

    currentUser
      .getIdToken(true) // true will force token refresh
      .then(() => {
        // Updates user cookie
        setUserCookie(currentUser)

        // Redirect back to where it was
        const decodedPath = window.decodeURIComponent(Router.query.redirect)
        Router.replace(decodedPath)
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // If any error happens on refresh, redirect to home
        Router.replace('/')
      })
  }, [currentUser])

  return (
    // Show a simple loading while refreshing token?
    <LoadingComponent />
  )
}

export default Refresh
```

Of course it will delay the user's first request if the token is expired, but it ensures a valid token without forcing user to login again.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thanks for contributing.

At work we're considering rolling out or own tokens that can be longer-lived, and will be created after checking for a short-lived Firebase token.

Comment: @MikaelGramont Firebase's longer lived session cookies seem to have been designed for exactly this use-case: https://hiranya911.medium.com/firebase-introducing-session-cookies-for-server-side-web-apps-fb46cce40b2